# django how export time to csv in one cell

Tags: python, django

I am using django outputing method to export data which includes time.

In csv I have:

```
Session Code, Round, Seller, Buyer, Price, Quantity, Created at
{% for t in data %}

    {{ t.bid.player.session.code}}, {{ t.bid.player.round_number }}, {{ t.ask.player.participant.code }}, {{ t.bid.player.participant.code }}, {{ t.traded_price }}, {{ t.traded_share }}, "{{ b.created_at }}"

{% endfor%}
```

The data I download would be:

```
...Create at
..."Dec. 12, 2019, 2:18pm"
```

Because of the comma, Dec. 12, 2019, 2:18pm are in three cells, but I want the time to be stored in one cell.

Comment: Please do *not* use templates to generate a csv. But a module like [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: A csv writer will normally escape the content, and put it between double quotes, so `"Dec. 12, 2019, 2:18pm"` (bit with the quotes). A good CSV reader, parses that as one cell.